# Bridge Class Functions in React Native

Tags: objective-c, swift, react-native, objective-c-swift-bridge

Say I have a class called `ExampleClass`.

Say I then write code like so:

```
@objc(ExampleClass)
class ExampleClass: NSObject {
  @objc class func exampleFunc() -> Void {

  }
}
```

With an Objective-C file header like so:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>

@interface RCT_EXTERN_MODULE(ExampleClass, NSObject)
  RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(exampleFunc)
@end
```

Which I then consume in my React Native app like so:

```
console.log('exampleClass', React.NativeModules.ExampleClass);
console.log('exampleFunc', React.NativeModules.ExampleClass.exampleFunc)
```

The first console log results in `{exampleFunc: f}`
The second results in `undefined`,

Calling the function: `React.NativeModules.ExampleClass.exampleFunc()` results in an app crash with:

> Exception 'exampleFunc is not a recognized Objective-C method.' was thrown while invoking setupLogger on target ExampleClass with params (

While changing only the Swift so that it reads:

```
@objc(ExampleClass)
class ExampleClass: NSObject {
  @obj func exampleFunc() -> Void {

  }
}
```

results in calling the function (which, yes) does nothing at present.

How can I expose class level variables? I am trying to write functional Swift, and I am using class methods to simulate structs.

Comment: Follow this link will help you: https://moduscreate.com/blog/swift-modules-for-react-native/

Answer (score 2):

I believe the problem is that `RCT_EXPORT_METHOD()` only works on instance methods, not class methods, according to my own similar problem and some discussion here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2311

My use case is trying to bridge a `getInstance()` method for a Swift singleton class. This is problematic because when you reference `NativeModules.ExampleClass` from javascript, which has been exported with `RCT_EXTERN_MODULE()`, RN calls `init()` on its own, which you don't want for a singleton (`init()` reference: https://samwize.com/2017/02/09/calling-a-view-controller-function-from-react-native/)

The best way I've found to accomplish this is pretty ugly. I have a dummy wrapper class that does nothing except call methods on the singleton, and this is the class I export to Objective C (and therefore to React Native). It's basically like this:

```
@objc(StupidWrapperClass)
class StupidWrapperClass : NSObject {
    @objc(pseudoSingletonSomeMethod)
    public func pseudoSingletonSomeMethod() {
        let singleton = ActualClass.getInstance()
        singleton.someMethod()
    }
}
```

and then in the .m bridge file:

```
@interface RCT_EXTERN_MODULE(StupidWrapperClass, NSObject)

RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(pseudoSingletonSomeMethod)

@end
```

You could do something like this for a class method, too:

```
@objc(StupidWrapperClass)
class StupidWrapperClass : NSObject {
    @objc(pseudoClassMethod)
    public func pseudoClassMethod() {
        ActualClass.theRealClassMethod()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I know I'm kinda late to the party but I recently faced the same problem and I fixed it using a different approach. Adding to the answer given above by @thejoelpatrol, a different approach would be to store the object's reference created by react native in some `static` variable that would be accessible by you. Then we can use the variable to access the object created by react-native anytime.

Whenever React Native tries to instantiate the class, it would come to the init. inside the init, we can save the reference to the object created by RN.

```
@objc public class MyClass {
    @objc public static var shared: MyClass?

    init() {
        MyClass.shared = self
    }
}
```

The `.m` bridge file is as follows:

```
@interface RCT_EXTERN_MODULE(MyClass)

RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(myClassMethod)

@end
```